# Detect if ajax call with Node.js (refreshing page without reloading)

Tags: jquery, node.js, express

I have a website and I would like to change pages without reloading the page, just refreshing the content. I'm using the express.js framework. Here's the code to change the page:

```
$("a").on('click', function(e) {
    pageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: pageUrl, success: function(data) {
            $('#main-content').html(data);            
        }
    });
});
```

Here's my "basic" layout with jade:

```
doctype html
    html(lang="fr")
        head
            title test
            block head
        body
            #main-content
                block body

            script(src="/js/vendor/jquery.js")
```

How do I detect with express.js an ajax call so I can only load the "block body" instead of all the layout.

I think it would be like:

```
if !ajax
    doctype
    ...
    block body
else
    block body
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you add new content to **DOM** when you click `a` element, the click handler won't work for newly added `a` elements.

This is not about **NodeJS**, but your **jQuery** code. You should add the click handler on `body` or `document`, because it's not changing when `a` element is clicked.

```
$(document).on('click', "a", function(e) {
    pageUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    e.preventDefault();    
    $.ajax({
        url: pageUrl, success: function(data) {
            $('#main-content').html(data);            
        }
    });
});
```

There is a solution for checking **AJAX** call in **Express.js** on [another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945118/detecting-ajax-requests-on-nodejs-with-express).

Comment: Yeah I know that :p. That's not the problem (I already know the thing with $(document)). The problem is I just want to update #main-content. Right now, what is sent to me is all the page (with doctype...). So I would like to detect with express.js what type of request is it.

Comment: @user3294481 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945118/detecting-ajax-requests-on-nodejs-with-express