# Passport.js - browser GET requests are OK, but AJAX requests from JS code are not?

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, passport.js

I have configured Passport on a Node.js server and am using the Twitter auth strategy primarily.

I am confused by a recent discovery that seems to suggest that a GET request with a browser URL (using the web browser searchbar) seems to be authenticated differently than a AJAX request from inside the application code. For example, if I login with Passport, I can access everything by pointing my browser to certain urls that make a request directly to the backend server. But any request by Angular or jQuery to the backend API seems to be unauthorized.

Could this be at all correct? If so, how would Passport know the difference between a browser request and the AJAX request from inside the JS code?

Comment: (1) You can tell if a request is a XHR (AJAX) request.
(2) Perhaps it's just an issue of not having the right cookies; is the Angular or jQuery code sitting in the exact same hostname as the Node.js server?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15945118/detecting-ajax-requests-on-nodejs-with-express

Comment: It could be incorrect coding, or a simple omission on your code. Of course there's no way to know that

Comment: yeah - the angular code is being served by a different server than the API server

Comment: nah the code is fine, it's an authentication issue that has to do with the way Passport works

Comment: "Nah the code is fine" seems like famous last words. :) Passport, generally, uses cookies for maintaining the session token. You might not be including those cookies in your ajax calls. Could you add a middleware step which logs the headers and compare between "normal" and "AJAX"?

Comment: @ChrisAnderson yep the code was right except I wasnt including the auth info in the AJAX requests. I just assumed it would be there by default when I wrote the question. You were correct and Quentins answer is correct in providing the solution.

Comment: Sounds about right. Glad you came to a solution. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, a cross-origin XHR request won't include cookies (which are normally used to maintain state in applications that require authentication).

You can change that by setting [withCredentials](http://www.w3.org/TR/XMLHttpRequest/#the-withcredentials-attribute):

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open(...);
xhr.withCredentials = true;
```

You may need to adjust the CORS rules on the server to say `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`.

See also [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Requests_with_credentials).

Comment: this seems to do the trick. I was able to do this with Angular by using $httpProvider.defaults.

Comment: thanks Quentin for this, I gave you the 150 points - however, one new problem, your solution works for HTTP, but not sure if it works for HTTPS. do you happen to know if using credentials with XHR is forbidden with HTTPS or requires an extra step?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but making requests to HTTPS from a page loaded over HTTP or vice versa may be blocked altogether as doing so gives a great opportunity to launch a man-in-the-middle attack against otherwise secure data.

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter auth strategy requires that the user be signed into Twitter and has allowed your "app" permission to access your Twitter account information. This cannot be done with a XHR because how would the user enter their Twitter credentials to log into Twitter if the user wasn't already signed in? How would the user approve the permissions your Twitter "app" is requesting if the request is sent via XHR?

This applies to all of the Passport strategies that utilize OAuth or OpenID. The user's browser has to go directly to the auth provider's site so that they can either A) login to the auth provider or B) approve the permissions you're requesting in your application. Once the user has done that the auth provider (in your case Twitter) will then redirect the user's browser back to your application's endpoint with some kind of token which your application will then use to request information from the auth provider (such as email address, full name, etc.)