# Node.js, Jade/Pug, how to serve full and part of template?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, pugjs

If request has been made via ajax, I would like to send only block content from page1.jade, if it's normal GET it should answer with this block built into layout.jade

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28540611/1643143

Comment: @avck33 that's not the point. I am looking for way to use single template file.

Answer (score 2):

Jade does not support [conditional layout switch](https://github.com/pugjs/pug/issues/52):

```
if type=='get'
  extends layout
block content
  p This is block content
```

This will render the page with the layout irrespective of the variable name.

> **METHOD 1**

A simple way would be to define the block content in a separate file and include it in your page1.jade, you can access that block independently then.

**layout.jade**

```
html
head
title My Site - #{title}
block scripts
body
  block content
  block foot
```

**page1.jade**

```
extends layout

block content
  include ./includes/block.jade
```

**includes/block.jade**

```
p This is the block content
```

This would be the way to handle requests in your routes file

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});
router.get('/block', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('includes/block', { title: 'Express' });
});
```

Modify it to handle the AJAX/browsers request.

> **METHOD 2**

The other *cleaner* way would be modifying your layout.jade itself for conditional

**layout.jade**

```
if type=='get'
  html
  head
  title My Site - #{title}
  block scripts
body
  block content
  block foot
```

And passing variable from your router while rendering the same page each time:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express',type:'get' });
});
router.get('/block', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Block Express' });
});
```