# Node.js Doesn't Recognize Ajax Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, express

I am trying to make a private page dedicated to an Ajax request. Here is the simple request.

```
window.onload = loaded;

function loaded(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', '/data_annotations', true);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if(this.status == 200){
            var data = xhr.responseText;
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        } else {
            console.log("Rip");
        }
    }
    xhr.send(); 
    //httpreq.abort();
}
```

Here is the node.js that it's running off of:

```
...
app.get('/', function(req, res, next){
    console.log("Connected Successfully.");
    res.render('home');
});

app.get('/data_annotations', function(req, res, next){
    if(req.xhr || req.headers.accept.indexOf('json') > -1) {
        const mc = mongo.MongoClient;  
        const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
        const dbName = 'practiceMDB';
        console.log("Got Data Annotations.");

        mc.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true }, (err, client) =>{
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                const db = client.db(dbName);
                data = db.collection('DataAnnotations');
                data.find({}).toArray(function(err, data){
                    res.send(data)
                });
                client.close();
            }
        });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/');
    }  
});

app.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('Server Started on Port '+port);
});
```

I only want /data_annotaion to run if it's from the Ajax request. If a user types in /data_annotations in the url, it should redirect them to the home page. When I ran this I got these results:

```
Server Started on Port 3000
Connected Successfully.
Connected Successfully.
```

This is indicating (to me) that the ajax request isn't registering as an ajax request, and is registering as a normal request. Further, I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I believe it is due to the redirection. The Ajax request gets redirected, it takes the response of the home page and is unable to parse it (I believe this to be happening because it cannot parse HTML text or string text - don't quote me on that). How do I get Node JS to register my Ajax request?

PS: I looked at this answer to determine if a request is Ajax or not, but it always determines my requests as not Ajax: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28540611/6804700

Comment: what makes you think `res.send(data)` is sending JSON? your client expects JSON  `JSON.parse(data)` - if you don't send JSON, you'll get an error here ... and `req.headers.accept.indexOf('json')` ... does the request header include an accept with the exact 4 characters `json`?

Comment: @JaromandaX Sorry, I a quite new to using Ajax and JSON.

Comment: well ... check the browser developer tools console. You should be able to see exactly what the request and response looks like, including headers - hint: `Accept` will likely be `*/*`

Comment: I'd suggest a custom header of your own if you want to avoid serving the content to a plain browser URL.

Comment: @JaromandaX it says it's coming from the home page (which is true), but the Ajax request is being sent to `/data_annotations`

Comment: yes, I know how it works - but look at your logic, then look at what headers are being sent ... or just read the answer below

Comment: @JaromandaX I didn't know about that. I was going through tutorials and no of them mentioned it.

Comment: didn't know about what? the browser developer tools console?

Comment: @JaromandaX I didn't know much about headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing - In your client-side code you need to set the accept header, because that is what you are looking for in your server side code.

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
```

Second you can use the following code to return the data as json in your server side code

```
res.json(data);
```

Another comment. It is bad practice to change the result type or redirect in an API. Your url is either returning JSON or redirecting to and HTML page which means the result is not consistent.

Comment: I am not use to Express JS syntax. I am trying to use it like I used MVC (which I heard it was like).

Comment: It is the same as MVC once you get your head around the non-blocking I/O and callbacks. It just takes some getting used to. A library you will used all the time is the async library - https://www.npmjs.com/package/async. It will make your code simpler and more readable

Comment: @RedJandal - Much better to program with promises and use them for async flow control and coordination rather than plain callbacks with the async library.  Promises and `async/await` are the future of pretty much all async development in Javascript.  Heck,  node.js v10 even has a promisified version of the `fs` library.

Comment: I'll take a look into it.

Comment: @jfriend00 - I totally agree. I just based my recommendation on the user's example and current experience without adding more complexity at this stage.

Comment: @RedJandal - But beginners should start with promises, not with the async library.  It's the way to learn from the beginning, not something to be learned later after you're more advanced.

Comment: @jfriend00 - My bad, I didn't know you were the authority on how to approach learning javascript and node.js. My opinion above is merely that, an opinion.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion - I'm just sharing mine for the benefit of the OP.